# Bitmap file generated in C is skewed

Tags: c, bitmap, bmp, bitmapimage

I'm having a problem where the output of my bitmap generator is very skewed. As you can see, the current generator is using a constant 24 bit by 24 bit array as the input, scaling it up to 600 bits by 600 bits, and generating a bitmap around the scaled image. I'm thinking the problem is in either the scaling or the pheader files, but I can't find the problem with the former and I'm not familiar enough with the BMP format to know how to fix the latter.

Where in my code does the problem lie, and how do I fix it? You can see a screenshot of the generated bitmap underneath the code (I can't succesfully upload the .bmp file itself to image hosts). The generated image *should* be a 3x3 checkerboard pattern. As a side note I also am having trouble opening the generated BMP on systems aside from my Ubuntu VM.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma pack (1)

#define _WIDTH 600
#define _HEIGHT 600
#define _BITCOUNT 1
#define _PPM 2835
#define _SLICE_WIDTH 24
#define _SLICE_HEIGHT 24
#define _SEQUENCE_LENGTH 20

void slicecpy(uint8_t* dst, uint8_t* src, int offset);
void scale(uint8_t* dst, uint8_t* src);

typedef struct {
  uint16_t signature;
  uint32_t fileSize;
  uint32_t reserved;
  uint32_t DataOffset;
} FileHeader;

typedef struct {
  uint32_t size;
  uint32_t width,height;
  uint16_t planes;
  uint16_t bitCount;
  uint32_t compression;
  uint32_t imageSize;
  uint32_t xppm,yppm;
  uint32_t colorsUsed;
  uint32_t colorsImportant;
} InfoHeader;

int main(void){
  FILE *fp;

  uint8_t* slices = calloc((_SLICE_WIDTH*_SLICE_HEIGHT)/8,sizeof(uint8_t));

  uint8_t *pixel_buf = calloc((_HEIGHT*_WIDTH*_BITCOUNT)/8,sizeof(uint8_t));
  uint8_t bram[]={0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0xff,0x00,0xff,
          0xff,0x00,0xff,
          0xff,0x00,0xff,
          0xff,0x00,0xff,
          0xff,0x00,0xff,
          0xff,0x00,0xff,
          0xff,0x00,0xff,
          0xff,0x00,0xff,
          0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0x00,0xff,0x00,
          0x00,0xff,0x00};

  FileHeader *fh = (FileHeader*)calloc(1,sizeof(FileHeader));
  InfoHeader *ih = (InfoHeader*)calloc(1,sizeof(InfoHeader));

  char i=0;
  char filename[12];
  uint32_t *bl = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
  uint32_t *wh = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));

  *bl=0x00000000;
  *wh=0xffffffff;

  // Set File Header Values
  fh->signature = 19778;
  fh->fileSize = sizeof(FileHeader)+sizeof(InfoHeader)+2*sizeof(uint32_t) + (_WIDTH*_HEIGHT)/8;
  fh->reserved = 0;
  fh->DataOffset = sizeof(FileHeader)+sizeof(InfoHeader)+2*sizeof(uint32_t);

  // Set Bitmap Header Values
  ih->size  = 40;
  ih->width     = _WIDTH;
  ih->height    = _HEIGHT;
  ih->planes    = 1;
  ih->bitCount  = _BITCOUNT;
  ih->compression = 0;
  ih->imageSize = (_WIDTH*_HEIGHT*_BITCOUNT)/8;
  ih->xppm = _PPM;
  ih->yppm = _PPM;
  ih->colorsUsed = (_BITCOUNT==1) ? 2 : 0;
  ih->colorsImportant = 0;

  slicecpy(slices,bram,0);
  scale(pixel_buf, slices);
  sprintf(filename,"image_%02d.bmp",i);
  fp=fopen(filename,"wb");

  fwrite(fh,14,1,fp);
  fwrite(ih,40,1,fp);
  //only need color table in monochrome one bit mode
  if(_BITCOUNT==1) fwrite(bl,sizeof(uint32_t),1,fp);
  if(_BITCOUNT==1) fwrite(wh,sizeof(uint32_t),1,fp);
  fwrite(pixel_buf,(_HEIGHT*_WIDTH*_BITCOUNT)/8,1,fp);

  fclose(fp);

  free(fh);
  free(ih);
}

void slicecpy(uint8_t* dst, uint8_t* src, int offset){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<(_SLICE_HEIGHT*_SLICE_WIDTH)/8;i++){
    *(dst+i) = *(src+i+offset);
  }
}

void scale(uint8_t* dst, uint8_t* src){
  int i,j;
  for(j=0;j<_WIDTH;j++){
    for(i=0;i<_HEIGHT;i++){
      dst[((i>>3)+j*(_WIDTH/8))] |=
    (src[((i/(_HEIGHT/_SLICE_HEIGHT))>>3) + 
    (j/(_WIDTH/_SLICE_WIDTH))*(24/8)] >> (((i/(_HEIGHT/_SLICE_HEIGHT))%8)&1))<<(i%8);
    }
  }
}
```

[Screenshot of BMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmC1o.png)

Comment: The size of each line of pixels needs to be rounded up to the next multiple of 32 bits...

Comment: When modifying the header, do I just change the file header, or should the new padding also be reflected in the x and y size fields in the BMP data header?

Comment: Also, is that padding for all bit depths? I'm only working in one bit

Comment: The padding is needed for all bit depths, yes.  In the header, height and width don't include padding, but the image size does.

Comment: I set _WIDTH and _HEIGHT to 576 (9*64) . Output becomes readable on windows and has proper pattern. There was still corruption when I set to 608 (19*32).

Comment: Ooops... make that `(_WIDTH * _BITCOUNT + 31) / 32 * 4` for the line size, so the multiplication by 4 doesn't happen before the division.

Comment: I tried what @B.Wolf did and that seems to have fixed the problem. The actual application for this program won't have variable image sizes, and 576 is close enough to 600 for my needs. Thanks both of you for the help!

Comment: It will work at 608 too, if you account for the padding throughout the code (including inside `scale()`)